# dbx can't find C source files

Tags: solaris, dbx, solaris-studio

[Env: Solaris 11 on i386; dbx from Solaris Studio 12.2; Sun C 5.7]

I am attempting to debug a large (~200 source code files) C program in dbx. I can invoke dbx with my executable, but I can't even get dbx to find the source code for `main()` - when I type `list main` inside dbx, I get

```
dbx: no source lines for "main"
```

I am debugging in the directory in which the final executable was compiled. The source for main is in `../sources/multithread/main.c`. I have looked inside main.o (located in the debugging/final compilation directory) and inside the final executable, and can see the filename/relative directory mentioned. Things I have tried:

- Adding `-I ../sources/multithread` to the `dbx` command line invocation
- Adding `pathmap <full_path_to_multithread_dir>` to `./.dbxrc`
- Copying `main.c` to the debug/final compilation dir
- Creating a small Hello World testcase and using dbx on this (this works)
- Only turning on debug info (`-g`) for `main.c` (thought I might have too many debug symbols, but that didn't help)

Are there architectural limitations I'm running into here? Missing some cc/linker options? dbx can't handle relative paths for debugging?